# Should each individual product have its own individual web page?

Tags: web, seo, html, web-standards

I'm new to web development so I don't know what is the norms for this. I'm trying to build a small e-commerce site. We have a lot of items. So should each item have its own separate page? Is it good for SEO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very important to have individual pages for each product.
Not only individual pages, you should have the URL of the page having product name.

For example, if you are selling a *Sony Xperia 2200 Mobile*, make a page such as `www.example.com/electronics/mobile/sony-experia-2200.php` or `asp.`.

If your site is dynamic, read on Google how to make your web URL static.

Look at how Amazon does it: `http://www.amazon.com/RCA-AH16100SN-16-Gauge-Speaker-Wire/dp/B0029HHIDY/`

Comment: There is no need (or benefit) to add an ending like `.php` or `.asp` in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As [Tim Berners-Lee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tim_Berners-Lee) [wrote](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/breadcrumbs/node/71):

> The [AWWW](http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/) says that everything of importance deserves a URI.

I'd say in general it is a good idea to have separate pages for each product.

For product *variants* (same product, different sizes/colors/…), you *could* also include all variants on the same product page. But it would be okay to use several pages/URLs here, too (depends on the exact situation).

What are the benefits of separate pages (and therefor having unique URLs for each product)?

- Each page can be linked/bookmarked/shared by users.
- Each page (= product) can have its own document-wide metadata (`meta`/`link` in `head`).
- Each page can be a result in search engines. If you'd include several different products on the same page, and someone searches for only one product of those, it's harder to rank with that page because the relevant content is only a (small) part of the page.

Also, if a customer adds a product to the shopping cart, visits the cart's page and clicks at the product title, the customer would see the page with the corresponding product. Otherwise the customer would see a page with several products and it wouldn't be necessarily clear which one of those is/was in the cart.